# Laravel5.8 Model Binding Route Arg 1 passed must be an instance of Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.8

Laravel Project Implemented with Localization and working fine. Making customization as the user can save the language(locale) in DB and here comes the issue.

1. User Able to Save Language in DB.
2. And When User try to Edit Language(locale) then getting this Issue.

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\CustomizeController::edit() must be an instance of App\Model\Customize, string given

in CustomizeController.php

```
    public function index()
{
    $data = array(
        'title' =>'Customize',
        'heading' =>'List',
        'customize' => Customize::where(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id])->first(),
    );
    if ($data['customize'])
    {
        return redirect()->route('customize.edit', ['locale' => app()->getLocale(), 'customize' => $data['customize']]); // Redirect to Edit Route If Language available in DB
    }
    return view('Customize.index')->with($data);
}
```

route:list command O/P as below:

```
GET|HEAD  | {locale}/customize/{customize}/edit | customize.edit | App\Http\Controllers\CustomizeController@edit | web,setlocale,auth
```

Even tried to hardcode from blade as:

```
<a href="{{ url(app()->getLocale().'/customize/1/edit') }}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
    </a>
```

Complete project [available here](https://github.com/syednizamudeen/claimy/tree/v2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty straight forward.

The `edit` method is called with the route parameters followed by the object you defined to get from the container.

Since you pass the `customize` param to the route, your method arguments should've been defined like follows:

```
public function edit(string $customize, App\Model\Customize $customizeModel)
{
    $customizeModel
        ->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
        ->update(['customize' => $customize]);

    $return response(); // whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Now i have to modify my controllers like `public function edit($locale, Customize $customize)` and `public function update($locale, Request $request, Customize $customize)`. Is it possible to make this change globally somewhere instead of changing in each and every controller??????????????? 

Anyway it works as expected!! Thanks!